# Convert Google Street View coverage layer in QGIS to a Maphub.net friendly format

Tags: qgis, google-maps, google-street-view

I have added an XYZ tile layer to QGIS with this address: [https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?hl=en-US&lyrs=svv|cb_client:apiv3&style=40,18&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}](https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?hl=en-US&lyrs=svv%7Ccb_client:apiv3&style=40,18&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D)
I want to export the coverage layer in order to use it on a map that I have in maphub.net, this website only accept importing data from GeoJSON, KML/KMZ, GPX, Shapefile ZIP and IGC files or JPG and PNG images.
What format I need to use? and how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can. Maphub doesn't seem to support XYZ tile layers as an import or as a custom basemap.

One thing you could possibly do would be to create a *static* version of the Tile layer as a PNG, but that would be at a fixed zoom and would go pixelated as you zoomed in. If you tried to create a PNG at a high zoom level, you'd quickly create something too big for Maphub to upload.

If you only want your Maphub map to be seen at a very small range of zoom or over a small area, that might work, although I tried a quick test and couldn't see how to create a PNG or JPG with embedded locations - maphub wants to show the image when you click on a placed marker.